# How to split a String from a list in dart

Tags: string, dart, split

I'm trying to sort some data in a `List<String>`. I want to split a long `String` of every other item and delete part of it. Data will be added to the list when the user performs an action.

Example of what could be in the list:

NOTE* These are not separate items in the list. Its all one `String`.

> "Cat walked across the road"

What I want from this String is just:

> "Cat"

Currently, I've initialised the list and split the `String` as shown below.

```
//Initialised List
 List<String> list = [];

//Method to split and delete String
String handleString(String items){

//Splits String
    items.split(" ").toString();

//TODO Delete String 

}
```

Output of this code looks like this:

> Cat, walked, across, the, road

The code below gets a single item from the list using `.text` get method.

```
for(var txt in list){
     String sentenceInList  = txt.text
print(txt.text);


}
```

Output :

> Cat walked across the road

Im not sure how to remove everything except the first word of every other potential item in the list?

Im looking to start at item one so if the items were as shown below, it would look like this:

Item 1: "Cat walked across the road"

> Output: Cat

Item 2: How are you today

> How are you today

and so on...

If anyone is able to help with this, it would be most appreciated?

Comment: so you need to return only the first word in the string interpreting a whitespace as a separator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to split your list on your first space character you could just use `substring` together with `indexOf`:

```dart
var str = 'Cat walked across the road';
var index= str.indexOf(' ');

var cat = str.substring(0, index); // The substring before the space.
var walked = str.substring(index); // The substringafter the space (including it, add +1 to the index to exclude the space).
```

or if you want to stick with `split` you can use `skip` to skip the first element:

```
var str = 'Cat walked across the road';
var split = str.split(' ');

var the = split.first; // The substring before the space.
var walked = split.skip(1).join(' '); // The substringafter the space.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Its very helpful! How would i split the string if Cat and Walked were together. For example: "Catwalked across the road" @Mattia

Comment: What would you use as separator between cat and walked?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. A good separator would probably be a ',' (Comma) as i would be deleting everything after the comma anyways. @Mattia

Comment: Hopefully thats what you mean by a separator. @Mattia